# How can I delete text before a delimiter in Linux

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to delete text from a line before delimiter.

For example:

```
(123434): hello::{apple,orange,mango}.
```

I need to delete text before first `:`. i.e. `(123434)`.

Is there any command in linux to perform this task?

Comment: You might want to look into `sed` or `awk`

Comment: Is this text part of a file, or part of a bash variable?

Comment: It is part of file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This `sed` command should do the trick.  The following command will overwrite the file:

```
sed -i 's/^[^:]*:/:/' file
```

To just print the output, remove the `-i` flag.  To put the output in a new file, remove the `-i` flag and redirect the output:

```
sed 's/^[^:]*:/:/' file > new_file
```

Comment: The line did the magic... the output replaced in the file itself..

Comment: when i compare two files  using sdiff, after removing the text from both files, the difference showing me the removed text for me. this command overwriting the file or just showing the output.

Comment: It worked.. Can i extract 'hello' and {apple,orange,mango} from my example by making simple changes in the above command?

Comment: @user80538, It's hard to tell what you want when you say *extract* in this context. Is this part of a larger shell script?  You may want to ask a new question with the details of the larger problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: It is just simple comparison of two files with same data but only need to find where the data is differing in two files. I need to check each individual section in the line . The data in individual sections may jumble. like  {apple,orange,mango} can be  {apple,mango,orange}.

Comment: @user80538 Still, comparing parts of lines on two files is a much different problem that deleting text before a delimiter. Furthermore, it's still unclear to me what you're trying to achieve; a separate question with an example is the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `cut`:

```
echo '(123434): hello::{apple,orange,mango}.' | cut -d: -f2-
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with a quite simple *Bash* instruction:

`mytext="(123434): hello::{apple,orange,mango}."`

`echo ${mytext#*)}`

This will print `: hello::{apple,orange,mango}.`. You can cut prefixes and suffixes in similar way. Moreover, prefix and suffix definitions can contain wildcards.

Cut prefix - up to first prefix wildcard match: `${variable#prefix}`

Cut prefix - up to last prefix wildcard match: `${variable##prefix}`

Cut suffix - up to first suffix wildcard match: `${variable%suffix}`

Cut suffix - up to last suffix wildcard match: `${variable%%suffix}`

It may look unclear at first sight, see the following example:

```
mytext="xAxBxAxBx"
echo ${mytext#*A}    # will print: xBxAxBx
echo ${mytext##*A}   # will print: xBx
echo ${mytext%B*}    # will print: xAxBxAx
echo ${mytext%%B*}   # will print: xAx
echo ${mytext%%C*}   # will print: xAxBxAxBx
```

In the last example, pattern doesn't match, so nothing is cut.

Comment: It'd be more robust to use `echo ${mytext#*:}:`. This will properly handle lines like `(123)(434): hello::{apple,orange,mango}.` and `123434: hello::{apple,orange,mango}`.

Comment: is there any way to modify the command echo ${mytext%%B*} to get text after B. in your example

Comment: @user80538 yes, just cut the text before B, inclusive ;-), i.e.: ${mytext#*B} for text after the first B, and ${mytext##*B} for text after the second B.